# For loop inside my custom function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a function that uses the number input I got from users to create the same amount of division inside of a container division.However, no matter what the number is, it always creates only 1 div. It seems like the for loop inside my function is being avoided.

I've tried to alter the function, checked number input whether it is defined or undefined.

```
function createGrid(parameter) {
  for (i = 0; i < parameter * parameter; i++); {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv = container.appendChild(div);
    newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'newDiv');
  }
  return newDiv;
}
```

Comment: What's `container`?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Remove the semicolon `;` after `for` loop.

Comment: Container is the id of my main division. I am trying to create divisions inside of this container division. That is why I'm using appendChild.

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense. `const div` is a new div you create. In the next line, you (re-)declare a global variable `newDiv` and set it to be `container`. Where is `container` defined? Then you apply the `newDiv` class to the container over and over again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have semicolon `;` after `for` loop which is essentially an empty statement.

That is the reason the `for` loop is not working as expected, and rest of your code is just creating one divider.

Remove the semicolon `;` to fix the issue.

Comment: @tosyn Then please mark this answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Additional to Nikhil's answer, here is how I would write it (without using global variables, which is considered to be bad practice in most cases):

```
function createGrid(parameter) {
  let newDiv;
  for (let i = 0; i < parameter * parameter; i++) {
    newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'newDiv');
    container.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
  return newDiv;
}
```

If you don't need to return the last div added, just remove the `let newDiv;` line and put the `const` keyword back into the first line of the `for` loop. Also remove the return value then.

```
function createGrid(parameter) {
  for (let i = 0; i < parameter * parameter; i++) {
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'newDiv');
    container.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}
```